# RN: The app goes disconnected from Metro in 'wireless debugging mode' even though the device is online and connected to ADB

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, adb

We start Metro and install the app. When we make changes in the code, it should refresh the app and display the changes. However, on my system, the app does not reflect the changes, and I can't reload the app by pressing 'r' in the console.

The temporary solution I use is to run 'adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081', then exit the app on the device and relaunch it manually. After that, pressing 'r' in the terminal console works.

However, after a few seconds, the app stops refreshing and reloading. I am not sure if the term 'My app disconnects from Metro automatically' is correct. Sometimes it holds for a few minutes, but other times it disconnects after a few seconds.

- I have tried unrestricting the app from battery optimization and disabling 'pause app activity if unused' in settings.
  wireless debugging is enabled
- tried with wireless auth timeout as disabled
- tried toggling developer mode in android
  System:
  Windows 11
  Android 13 (Moto G54) [physical device]
  React: 18.2.0
  React Native: 0.72.7"

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer:
`192.168.0.101:8081` solved the issue. ip and port may differ.

Detail:
OK I found the solution. I set [pc ip]:[port] in the app
open setting by pressing d from metro console or
by shaking the android device would open the pop up

the go to setting and look for "... host & port ... " option.
and enter [pc ip]:[port]. i.e 192.168.0.1:8081 in my case.

that's it. It works like charm. Even screen is locked and unlcoked backed still app is connected